# CASE statement for double and null data

Tags: mysql, case

I have data

```
 Name    | Type    | status   | Exp    | Idx
 Aaa      Attc       1          0        50
 Bbb      Attc       1          0        50
 Bbb      Detc       1          0        61
```

with Query statement

```
 MAX(case type = "Detc" 
 WHEN status = "0" THEN "Sch"
 WHEN status = "1" THEN "Done"
 ELSE "Sch2" END) Detc
```

I expect data to be

```
 Name    | Attc    | Detc
 Aaa      Done       Sch
 Bbb      Done       Done
```

but Aaa Detc part is Done, it should be Sch. it read max type "Attc" Not "Detc"

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
SeLect 
  `Name`
 ,MIN(IF(`Type` = 'Attc',IF(`status` = 0,'Sch','Done'),'Sch2')) Attc
 ,MIN(IF(`Type` = 'Detc',IF(`status` = 0,'Sch','Done'),'Sch2')) Detc
From table1
Group By `Name`
;
```

Gives you

```
Name    Attc    Detc
Aaa     Done    Sch2
Bbb     Done    Done
```

Which **only works**, because Sch and Sch2 are "greater than" Done